# FedEx 556 - No valid services available. when there should be

Tags: wsdl, opencart, fedex

Hi I'm trying to use the wsdl api to get shipping cost calculated for my website.
I'm using opencart and this module (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2055&filter_search=fedex&sort=e.date_modified&order=DESC).
On checkout I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING::556::There are no valid services available.
```

But I tried the same from and to address on the calculator on the fedex website and it gives me two services: International Priority and International Economy

This is the debug data I have:

```
Array
(
[WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
    (
        [UserCredential] => Array
            (
                [Key] => REDACTED
                [Password] => REDACTED
            )

    )

[ClientDetail] => Array
    (
        [AccountNumber] => REDACTED
        [MeterNumber] => REDACTED
    )

[TransactionDetail] => Array
    (
        [CustomerTransactionId] =>  *** Rate Request v9 using PHP *** 
    )

[Version] => Array
    (
        [ServiceId] => crs
        [Major] => 9
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

[ReturnTransitAndCommit] => 1
[RequestedShipment] => Array
    (
        [DropoffType] => REQUEST_COURIER
        [ShipTimestamp] => 2011-09-28T09:02:01+00:00
        [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
        [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
            (
                [Amount] => 2000
                [Currency] => EUR
            )

        [Shipper] => Array
            (
                [Address] => Array
                    (
                        [StreetLines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                                [1] => 
                            )

                        [City] => Ronchis
                        [StateOrProvinceCode] => 
                        [PostalCode] => 33050
                        [CountryCode] => IT
                        [Residential] => 1
                    )

            )

        [Recipient] => Array
            (
                [Address] => Array
                    (
                        [StreetLines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                                [1] => 
                            )

                        [City] => villach
                        [StateOrProvinceCode] => 
                        [PostalCode] => 9500
                        [CountryCode] => AT
                        [Residential] => 1
                    )

            )

        [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
            (
                [PaymentType] => SENDER
                [Payor] => Array
                    (
                        [AccountNumber] => 263150082
                        [CountryCode] => IT
                    )

            )

        [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
        [PackageCount] => 1
        [PackageDetailSpecified] => 1
        [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
        [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Weight] => Array
                            (
                                [Value] => 34
                                [Units] => KG
                            )

                        [Dimensions] => Array
                            (
                                [Length] => 48
                                [Width] => 53
                                [Height] => 122
                                [Units] => CM
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)


----------

-- NUSOAP -- Array
(
[HighestSeverity] => WARNING
[Notifications] => Array
    (
        [Severity] => WARNING
        [Source] => crs
        [Code] => 556
        [Message] => There are no valid services available. 
        [LocalizedMessage] => There are no valid services available. 
    )

[TransactionDetail] => Array
    (
        [CustomerTransactionId] =>  *** Rate Request v9 using PHP *** 
    )

[Version] => Array
    (
        [ServiceId] => crs
        [Major] => 9
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this error, and it turned out that the issue was an invalid postal code. Double check that you are specifying the "Shipper" information correctly.

Also, if that doesn't work give the FedEx customer support phone number a try. We would not have figured this issue out without their help.

Comment: Ya. FEDEX API is picky about shipper information.  I submitted USA instead of US and it wouldn't give me any services.  I notice on the question no province is listed in shipper information.  Perhaps thats the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having this issue .. but with Joomla, Virtuemart. Because the FedEx server is the same so may be my solution could help somebody else too..

Here are the main things what I fixed to fix this issue.

1. Product's Weight should be less than the limit if you've set any as Maximum Weight.
2. If you are using any packaging has more weight than FedEx's provided box i.e. 25KG BOX or 10KG box, then always use "Your Own packaging"
3. it's true, do keep an eye on ZIP===States (i was testing and put wrong state with different zip) And this ZIP should be added in "Shop's Address" because this is considered as FROM and the destination address as well.
4. Do note if products have added weights. LWH (Length, Width, Height).

Mine issue resolved after weeks of trouble! I wish somebody else could also resolve this issue if facing.

I was facing following error

```
"10 kg packaging box is **only** Available at FedEx World Service Center® locations!"
```

[image: Source]

which was a big help to resolve the limitation i've set.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happen when one of the bellow cases.

1. Country given is not associated with FedEx account.
2. Origin address is not real, Especially the post code.
3. The given packagingType is available in your country.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a ServiceType. One of these:

```
EUROPE_FIRST_INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY 
FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT 
FEDEX_2_DAY 
FEDEX_2_DAY_AM
FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT 
FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT 
FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER 
FEDEX_FIRST_FREIGHT 
FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY 
FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY 
FEDEX_GROUND 
FIRST_OVERNIGHT 
GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY
INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY
INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_FREIGHT
INTERNATIONAL_FIRST
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_FREIGHT
PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT
SMART_POST
STANDARD_OVERNIGHT
```

Use it in the same level as the DropoffType

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the Zip Code set to required.

You can do that in System -> Localization -> Countries.

It is not required by default in opencart, and the fedex shipping system will not work without it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be caused by requesting insurance in a country that doesn't support it, such as Canada.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and the solution was trimming extra spaces from the end of the address, city & postal code.  After that, all was well again.

I don't know why FedEx's API all of a sudden stopped accepting the extra spaces, but who knows...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by trying to ship internationally from the US to Italy, and having specified a `SignatureOptionDetail` of `NO_SIGNATURE_REQUIRED`. Changing this to `SERVICE_DEFAULT` fixed it.